# Read from Spark RDD a Kryo File

Tags: apache-spark, kryo

I'm Spark & Scala newbie.

I need to read and analyze a file in Spark that it has written in my scala code with Kryo serialized:

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output

val kryo:Kryo = new Kryo()
val output:Output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("filename.ext",true))

//kryo.writeObject(output, feed) (tested both line)
kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, myScalaObject)
```

This is a pseudo-code for create a file with my object (myScalaObject) serialized, that is a complex object.

The file seems that write well, but i have problem when I read it in Spark RDD

pseudo-code in Spark:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local")
    .setAppName("My application")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")


conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "myScalaObject")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val file=sc.objectFile[myScalaObject]("filename.ext")

val counts = file.count()
```

When I try to execute it i receive this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Job aborted: Task 0.0:0 failed 1 times (most recent failure: 
Exception failure: java.io.IOException: file: filename.ext not a SequenceFile)
```

Is possible read this type of file in Spark?

If this solution is not possible, what is a good solution for create a complex file structure to read in Spark?

thank you

Comment: `objectFile` is used to load an `RDD` saved as a SequenceFile containing serialized objects. Why not just use Kryo to read the objects and use `parallel` to generate a `RDD`?

Comment: @zsxwing Thank you, very good idea, I try it. But I have many small (5-20mb) and do not want to parallelize the contents of files. Is there any way to parallelize the filename and then each server read its files?

Comment: Create a RDD with the file names and read the content with `map`?

Comment: @zsxwing I have create a RDD with the file names and paralelize it, work fine. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read with `objectFile`, write out the data with `saveAsObjectFile`.

```
val myObjects: Seq[MyObject] = ...
val rddToSave = sc.parallelize(myObjects) // Or better yet: construct as RDD from the start.
rddToSave.saveAsObjectFile("/tmp/x")
val rddLoaded = sc.objectFile[MyObject]("/tmp/x")
```

Alternatively, as `zsxwing` says, you can create an RDD of the filenames, and use `map` to read the contents of each. If want each file to be read into a separate partition, parallelize the filenames into separate partitions:

```
def loadFiles(filenames: Seq[String]): RDD[Object] = {
  def load(filename: String): Object = {
    val input = new Input(new FileInputStream(filename))
    return kryo.readClassAndObject(input)
  }
  val partitions = filenames.length
  return sc.parallelize(filenames, partitions).map(load)
}
```

Comment: You can now also use `sc.wholeTextFiles`. I've got to update the answer sometime.